# padding-right not applying to last child

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

Trying to make an image timeline interface, and I'm a little stuck. The marker is always at the center so the first element has `padding-left: 50%` which is working fine. However, I also want the last element to have `padding-right: 50%` so I can scroll all the way to the end of the last element.

Here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/da3hk2xz/

As you can see `#timeline:last-child` is not being applied.

```js
var timeline = document.getElementById("timeline");

for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = "http://placehold.it/300x150?text=" + i
  timeline.append(img)
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#timeline {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#timeline:nth-child(1) {
  padding-left: 50%;
}

#timeline:last-child {
  padding-right: 50%;
}

#marker {
  /* http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/ */
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 35px 17.5px 0 17.5px;
  border-color: #007bff transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 115px;
  /* 150 - 35 */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#line {
  width: 2px;
  height: 115px;
  /* 150 - 35 */
  background-color: purple;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="timeline"></div>
<div id="marker-container">
  <div id="marker"></div>
  <div id="line"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/da3hk2xz/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply changing the selectors in question from what you have to this below should work:

```
#timeline :nth-child(1) {
  padding-left: 50%;
}

#timeline :last-child {
  padding-right: 50%;
}
```

The reason for this is that the last "phrase" in the selector is the element to which the styles will be applied. In your fiddle, the last "phrase" was the `#timeline` element itself, thus it was receiving the padding. Putting a space between `#timeline` and `:last-child` made the `:last-child` phrase the last one, and since the space in the selector means "any decendant", the decendant will receive the padding.

---

In plain english:

`#timeline:last-child`: The last child, of a parent element, that *also* has an id of `timeline`.
`#timeline :last-child`: The last element that is a child of the element with an id of `timeline`.

Targeting the *direct decendant* would work as a safer and more efficient solution as well:

```
#timeline > :nth-child(1)
#timeline > :last-child
```

CSS is fun.

Comment: Didn't know css was space-sensitive, this explains a lot - thanks!

Comment: It's more correctly "no-space sensitive" :) A more efficient solution to your problem would be to change the selector to target the _direct decendant_  in your `#timeline` element like: `#timeline > :last-child`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Changing this to the correct answer because it offers a better way to answer the question in the title - along with an explanation.

Comment: Thanks for that! Glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

Tested this and it worked out

```
#timeline img:nth-child(1) {
  padding-left: 50%;
}

#timeline img:last-child {
  padding-right: 50%;
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer. You should use the `:*-child` psuedo selectors on the images not the `div`.

Comment: Thank you! I like this answer the best because it keeps the scroll overflow within the timeline. Thank you for everyone else who took the time to submit a jsfiddle solution.

Comment: I actually wrote the code targeting the image in my comment before this one -- guess you didnt see it :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a cool solution you might like:

Instead of padding, use `pseudo` flex items.

```
#timeline::before {
  content: "";
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  background-color: red;
}

#timeline::after {
  content: "";
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/da3hk2xz/3/)

Comment: This is very cool, I'm a fan of flexbox. I think I will leave the current answer as accepted for future searchers.

Comment: Also, not sure if this affects the bounding box of each child? Will need them to be the same to calculate the intersection between marker and box.

Comment: Test it out. It appears to work well in the fiddle demo.

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

https://jsfiddle.net/da3hk2xz/1/

Your layout uses a bit much absolute positioning, so I had to change it around a bit. The main thing was that I added `#right-padding` and `#timeImgContainer`.